# array functions C++ finding highest value

Tags: c++

I am trying to return the highest value from the array by using an function but I cant seem to get it to work right can someone help. So I want to show the highest values in array 1,2,3 and 4 but I cant seem to get the function to work.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void averScore(int test[], int size);
void highScore(int test[], int size);
void lowestScore(int test[], int size);



int main()
{

    const int SIZE1 = 5;
    const int SIZE2 = 6;
    const int SIZE3 = 4;
    const int SIZE4 = 5;

    int set1[SIZE1] = { 90,85, 88, 80, 85 };
    int set2[SIZE2] = { 89, 75, 78, 82, 83, 80 };
    int set3[SIZE3] = { 88, 82, 88, 90 };
    int set4[SIZE1] = { 85, 87, 88, 90, 92 };

    highScore(set1, SIZE1);

    return 0;
}

void highScore(int num[], int size)
{
    int highnum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (num[i] > highnum)
            highnum = num[i];
        cout << num[i];
    }
    cout << highnum;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what is not working  exactly  , what are the results/errors that you get

Comment: Looks right... what's the problem?

Comment: What's wrong exactly? You should use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: Your code is fine.

You might want to change both cout's so you can actually see what is printed for what. For example:

    `cout << "Looped through: " << num[i] << endl; `

and

    `cout << "Highest number is: " << highnum << endl; `

Comment: I actually tried your code and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You called "highScore" function only for SET1.

If you want for all the four, you have to call the function for each set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you need the `stdafx.h` library. For me, it works nicely without including it.

And add a new line `endl` after the `cout` statement like this `cout << num[i] << endl;` and `cout << highnum << endl;`